# XAML bindings not working in Release mode but works in Debug mode

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I'm using a `CarouselView` that I've bound to a `IEnumerable<T> list` to display a preview of my files in that list with the filename and using the filepath as a image preview.

This binding works as expected when I debug my application with the filename and image preview showing as intended according to each file. However, when I test my application in Release mode, the binding for the filename fails while the binding for my filepath still works.

To show you what I mean, here are some screenshots from both Debug and Release:

[Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp0UU.jpg)  // [Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJwXw.jpg)

The application should function like the debug screenshot where the filename is visible at the top of the frame.

Here is my XAML and code-behind to better understand what is going wrong:

XAML:

```
    <!--Carousel of files selected preview with binding to the Files variable in the codebehind-->
            <CarouselView x:Name="preview" IsVisible="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" PeekAreaInsets="20" >
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Frame  HasShadow="True"
                                   IsVisible="True"
                                   BorderColor="Black"
                                   CornerRadius="5"
                                   Margin="5,10,5,10"
                                   HeightRequest="500"
                                   WidthRequest="500"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Start">
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding FileName}" IsVisible="True"></Label>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding FullPath}"
                                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                                           HeightRequest="500"
                                           WidthRequest="500"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
```

Code-behind:

```
    //<--Summary: Gives users a preview of the files they selected before uploading-->
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FileView : ContentPage
    {
        public static string fileID; //Upload filename
        private IEnumerable<FileResult> pickedFiles; //List of picked files
        public IEnumerable<FileResult> Files {
            get => pickedFiles;
        }
        public string SelectedTime { get; set; } //Binding for user selected transfer time
        public bool SelectedCompression { get; set; } //Binding for user selected compression type

        public FileView( IEnumerable<FileResult> pF)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SelectedTime = "1"; //Sets default transfer time to 1 minute
            this.pickedFiles = pF;
            this.BindingContext = this;
        }
```

Comment: Since  it works in debug , I don't think the issue is caused by the code . You could check if can get the filename in code behind within release mode .

Comment: if you use a “linker” in order to reduce your app size and if you didn't preserve your FileResult class, linker may remove some of your code in release mode. You can try to add [Preserve(AllMembers = true)] above to your FileResult class. Maybe it can be solve.

Comment: Since on release bindings are compiled the error comes from here. One of the causes could be an incorrectly set `x:DataType` somewhere upper in your xaml that you didn't show in the question.